# RPi Zero 2: What is the black part next to GPIO 26?

Tags: hardware, pi-zero-w-2

I ordered a Raspberry PI Zero 2 a while ago. Today I wanted to use it the first time. I inserted a SD card with Raspberry Pi OS and powered the Zero 2 with an iPhone power supply. Nothing happened. So I compared the Zero 2 with pictures of other Zero 2. I found out, that the little black part next to GPIO 26 is missing, the one that is circled at the image. What kind of part is it?[image]
[image]

Comment: please add a clear, closeup picture of the area where the part is missing

Comment: Why? If you can’t answer my question when the part in question can be seen, you will not be able to answer it because of picture where it can’t be seen, right? It’s just two empty solder pads.

Comment: so that we can see how many pins are connected to the component ... it may help with determining what the device might be ... size of the traces may give a hint

Comment: try to find a datasheet for the 12 pin IC ... it is probably a regulator ... the datasheet may contain a schematic diagram that closely matches the circuit you have

Comment: I added the best picture I could take.

Comment: Could the 12 pin IC be a PAM2306AYPKE voltage regulator, as depicted in the [Zero 2 W schematics](https://bit.ly/38BlrV8), @jsotola?

Comment: definitely looks like it ... the two dark gray components are the inductors on pin 2 and 8 ... use a magnifying glass and an ohmmeter to determine which pin connects to the missing component